# Dropdowns on NavBar issues

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, navbar, dropdown, popper.js

I am currently learning all things Bootstrap 4 v4.4.1 and I've been stuck on a Dropdown Issue where it wouldn't function (ie not dropdown). I discovered after documentation and solved issue reading in various places this was a "popper" issue and I cut and paste the popper on the solved issue into my boilerplate

"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"

and hey presto dropdown functions, brilliant!.

However replacing the above with (the latest popper?)

"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.4.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha256-FT/LokHAO3u6YAZv6/EKb7f2e0wXY3Ff/9Ww5NzT+Bk=" crossorigin="anonymous"

the dropdown again ceases to function.

What am I missing here?

Bueller... Bueller... Bueller... Anyone?

Comment: Why not just use Popper.js 1.11.0?

Comment: Well yes ihodonald but not using (the latest?) 2.4.0 version might impact on other issues or do I have to use multiple poppers?

Comment: You mentioned nothing about "other issues". You should make your question more descriptive. Also, if you're using a library like React, for example, you could use something like Reactstrap. Right now, you're trying to install the dependencies using a CDN, manually, when you could be using something like Webpack to create a dependency tree.